# Jsp takes long to load

Tags: java, performance, jsp, servlets

My page is taking too long to load.After a idle time on a certain page,my main page takes 22s to load when I try to return.And it's always 22s,I don't know why.What can I do for tune/solve it? I'm using jsp with JSTL tags and the main page's content is basically a table with many objects(returned from a method).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4K5W.png)

Comment: Look at the logs, profile it, etc.

Comment: The logic in "a method" seems to be a likely suspect, use a debugger to step through it and see if a particular piece of code is taking a long time to complete. And then you can ask a question which is far more specific.